# How to assign a default 'fallback' provider for a specific type in Google Guice

Tags: java, guice

The use case I have is this:

An object requests a unbound @Named injection of a specific type. I want Guice to tell my 'fallback' provider what the name value was (or give me the entire annotation) so my provider can still provide an implementation based on the name value.

The @Named value is thus used as a key to find the correct implementation at runtime. If an implementation *is* found based on the @Named, then the provider should not be consulted.

Comment: Please post some code, I dont really get what you are trying ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guice is basically a map from a (annotation, type) tuple to a `Provider<T>`. There is no more a way to bind a default binding to all unbound `@Named` instances than there is to bind an entire range of doubles to a single string in a `Map<Double, String>`.

If you have a convenient array or Collection of all `@Named`values you want, you could loop through them and bind them all to some kind of default provider, which you could then hack using `Modules.override()` or an `if` block within the loop:

```
public class DefaultNameModule extends AbstractModule() {
  @Override public void configure() {
    for (String name : YOUR_LIST_OF_NAMES) {
      if (properties.contains(name)) {
        bindConstant(properties.get(name)).annotatedWith(Names.named(name));
      } else {
        bind(Foo.class)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named(name))
            .toProvider(new MyProvider(name));
      }
    }
  }

  private static class MyProvider extends Provider<Foo> {
    final String name;

    MyProvider(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    @Override public Foo get() {
      return someValueBasedOn(name);
    }
  }
}
```

If this is too complex for your taste, remember that you can always inject an instance of a one-method object that wraps the `Properties` access for you, calculating a default if needed.

Comment: Ok I guess that answers my question, too bad it doesn't solve my problem. I was hoping I could hook into the way guice injects members by giving my all the data it has and then let me assist/work it out for Guice. Pehaps I should look into extending Guice...